# When do you find the time to answer questions?

Tags: answers, subjective, discussion

I rarely find the time to browse SO/SF/SU looking for questions that I can answer. So I'm really curious to know when most of you find the time to answer questions?

Comment: You live in Perth, doesn't that mean by definition you have plenty of time?

Comment: Perth is becoming a new meme on its own.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/what-is-the-ideal-time-zone-to-live-in-for-maximum-reputation/21008#21008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- At home (as a break from writing/editing, usually)
- On the train/bus
- At work while waiting for builds/deployments etc
- Walking to/from the station, via my phone (normally comments rather than answers, admittedly)
- Waiting for my eldest son's swimming lesson to finish
- Occasionally in front of the TV

Comment: Nice ideas Jon! Keep 'em coming.

Comment: Ah the beauty of PHP: no compile/build/deployment steps. :)

Comment: @cletus: You say beauty, I say lack of opportunity for micro-breaks :)

Comment: How long has your new book been delayed, Jon? :)

Comment: @Vinko: That's a very good question... I've no idea, but SO has certainly helped to get answers to a few questions which I had when writing :)

Answer (score 9):

I don't let work get in the way.

Comment: You mean you answer questions on the sly at your *workplace*??

Comment: Don't you? What else are you going to do at work?

Comment: @Jeremy, whatever you're currently doing, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: The only thing work is good for!

Comment: TheTXI, you are not good enough for a check mark!

Comment: The fact that a check mark was even given in the first place and then immediately switched over as soon as Skeet came to play is hilariously sad.

Answer (score 3):

I take small breaks from work throughout the day to browse. I consider it study, and as such benefits my work.

Comment: How did you convince your seniors to allow you to continue such "insincere" activity?

Comment: Fastest checkmark of the day! Jeremy, why have you asked in the first place?

Comment: I accepted the only valid answer .. until Jon replied.

Comment: Obviously that check mark was being kept warm until Jon Skeet came along.

Comment: @Jeremy: I didn't have to convince anybody. Employees have down-time, especially programmers. I think they would be rather happy that I'm using my downtime to sharpen my skills rather than smoking out back.

Answer (score 2):

I have insomnia, and this is a hell of a lot better than aimlessly browsing wikipedia...

also it makes for a nice break periodically throughout the workday. I've gotten some great inspiration for features (or the implementation of a feature) by browsing through the site.

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/

Comment: Please do not visit that site without your ad blocker turned on. My eyes!

Comment: Flashblock is a good thing...

Comment: Didn't realise that TvTropes had any ads. After all this time...

Comment: Oh my dear lord...!

Answer (score 0):

Since I work from home most of the week, I have my desktop PC on the left and work's laptop on the right, monitors side by side and [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) acting as KVM.

My brain is wired to multitask, so it's become a reflex action to kick the mouse over to the left and read SO or Facebook or IRC for thirty seconds in between thoughts, then kick it back over to the laptop to write my next few lines of code or reply to a text message on Skype from my colleagues.

Somehow this leads me to getting my work done — *fast* — at the same time as writing a slew of SO answers and getting worked up about the number of edits my OCD is driving me to do.

It's pretty cool.