# Meta sort not by votes?

Tags: support, meta, sorting

I was browsing Meta as I sometimes do to keep myself up to date on the community and looked at this question:
[A badge that rewards "prophetic" downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/134551/a-badge-that-rewards-accurate-downvoting)

As I scrolled down, I noted a couple of "3" voted answers ABOVE a "5" voted one.  Why is that?  Am I missing some important point of votes here in particular?  Is this a bug?

Comment: Are you set to sort by Active? The vote count may have also changed since you loaded the page; vote count updates automatically every X seconds but doesn't alter the sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you have chosen a different sorting. Active perhaps?

Comment: This is a perfect place to wrap an image in a `<pre>`...

Comment: It looks to be a combination of this, and the comment by @Ben Brocka as I was looking at answers that seems to be in play.  Odd that is was/is set to "active" by default (at least to me) as the "left most" of the choices though :)

Comment: @Lix Oh you and your perfect behavior. Just stop it. ;) Thanks.

Comment: [Are you sure](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gUpd0.png), @Lix...?

Comment: @arj - Most certainly... White background for both is a nightmare...   Yes it looks overly padded on mobile but hey - at least the image boundaries are defined....  Correct me if I'm wrong, but I assume you had to wait till you got to your desktop/laptop to crop that screenshot;  If you are viewing the site on mobile it is becuase you are simply in  between computers.  `You can't please all the people all the time`  :P

Comment: @Lix What, no solution to Arjan's problem? How disappointing... :)

Comment: @Lix, as for "overly padded": I assume you're not blaming the mobile theme for rendering your newlines and spaces? (Using a blockquote would be different; you're aligning using whitespace.) Well, you know how I feel about folks editing other people's post to make them look the way *they* prefer; just to repeat that. (Adding `<kbd>` is worse, so I won't stalk you on this.) But, wait, using mobile is not *in between computers*, it's 2012, and it's the only way to get to [be #1](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21150/when-do-you-find-the-time-to-answer-questions/21153#21153)! ;-)