# Accepted answer not generating reputation?

Tags: support, daily-reputation-limit

In the [faq](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) it states:

> A maximum of 30 votes can be cast per
>   user per day, and you can earn a
>   maximum of 200 reputation per day
>   (although accepted answers are immune
>   to this limit). Also, please note that
>   votes for any posts marked "community
>   wiki" do not generate reputation.

Yet I have an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717599/defeating-a-poker-bot/3168983#3168983) that doesn't seem to be generating more reputation when it gets upvoted?

Just curious!  Don't mind either way but just thinking maybe the FAQ is out of date or something?

Also, while we are on the topic, [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20998/what-is-the-ideal-time-zone-to-live-in-for-maximum-reputation) got me thinking, why doesn't SO just use the limit of your last 24 hours activity, not a set amount?  So if your cap is 200 per day, and someone gives you +10rep at lunchtime, it should give you a +190cap until lunchtime the next day, not based on fixed hard timezone limits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How does a post become a Community Wiki post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts/11741#11741).

Your [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717599/defeating-a-poker-bot/3168983#3168983) has been marked as **community wiki**, since

> The post has been edited eight (8) times by the original owner.

Comment: All the revisions are mine, except one or two which were simply to remove spelling mistakes!  I was simply adding to the answer as it was a popular question and I wanted to make it as comprehensive as I could, shame it got turned to a Wiki, any way to revert that?

Comment: Hmph apparently not, surely this disuades me from improving my answer in some cases?

Comment: @tom excellent post though, but this is the way of all things -- they can't generate rep forever .. so think about your *next* great post :)

Comment: @Tom: For most questions, (99% of which will be less complicated than the one referenced here) it should *always* take less than 8 edits to get the answer into a satisfactory state. Yours is an edge case. One of the downsides of being great in an unexpected way is that you usually don't get appropriate compensated. Enjoy the fame, however!